# sort array of objects by it's string value

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have this object

```
var obj = [
    {id: 31, name: "Tiebreak 1", type: 2},
    {id: 32, name: "Tiebreak 2", type: 2},
    {id: 25, name: "Set 1", type: 0},
    {id: 33, name: "Tiebreak 3", type: 2},
    {id: 26, name: "Set 2", type: 0},
    {id: 34, name: "Tiebreak 4", type: 2},
    {id: 35, name: "Tiebreak 5", type: 2},
    {id: 27, name: "Set 3", type: 0},
    {id: 28, name: "Set 4", type: 0},
    {id: 29, name: "Set 5", type: 0}
]
```

How can I sort it like this?

```
var obj = [
    {id: 25, name: "Set 1", type: 0},
    {id: 31, name: "Tiebreak 1", type: 2},
    {id: 26, name: "Set 2", type: 0},
    {id: 32, name: "Tiebreak 2", type: 2},
    ...
]
```

Comment: Create a custom sort function with your logic

Comment: [MDN documentation for the `.sort()` method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) A good first step would be to describe in detail what your ordering criteria are; it's not at all clear from what you posted.

Comment: It's tennis data. after set it should be tiebreak (something like extra time). I can't get how can I sort like that

Comment: @gsiradze you can't really do that with `.sort()` then. You would probably be better off re-structuring the data.

Comment: Your data structure is wrong.   A `Tiebreak` is not a separate entity that's distinct from a `Set`, it's just a special sort of `Game` that can only appear as _part of_ a `Set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like:

```js
var obj= [{id:31,name:"Tiebreak 1",type:2},{id:32,name:"Tiebreak 2",type:2},{id:25,name:"Set 1",type:0},{id:33,name:"Tiebreak 3",type:2},{id:26,name:"Set 2",type:0},{id:34,name:"Tiebreak 4",type:2},{id:35,name:"Tiebreak 5",type:2},{id:27,name:"Set 3",type:0},{id:28,name:"Set 4",type:0},{id:29,name:"Set 5",type:0}]

console.log(obj.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.name.split(' ')[1] - b.name.split(' ')[1] || a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could group the same number together and order by `'Set'` and `'Tiebreak'` later.

```js
var array = [{ id: 31, name: "Tiebreak 1", type: 2 }, { id: 32, name: "Tiebreak 2", type: 2 }, { id: 25, name: "Set 1", type: 0 }, { id: 33, name: "Tiebreak 3", type: 2 }, { id: 26, name: "Set 2", type: 0 }, { id: 34, name: "Tiebreak 4", type: 2 }, { id: 35, name: "Tiebreak 5", type: 2 }, { id: 27, name: "Set 3", type: 0 }, { id: 28, name: "Set 4", type: 0 }, { id: 29, name: "Set 5", type: 0 }];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getParts(o) {
        return o.name.split(' ');
    }
    var order = { Set: 1, Tiebreak: 2 },
        aa = getParts(a),
        bb = getParts(b);

    return aa[1] - bb[1] || order[aa[0]] - order[bb[0]];
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```